# Small Title bar on SwiftUI macOS Window

Tags: swiftui, window, titlebar

How can I create the small TitleBar like in the old days the Inspector windows has; like the download window in Xcode?

In the @main struct I did use in the body the following code but both doesn't shows me what I want.

```
 .....
 #if os(macOS)

    Window("Folios", id: "folios") {
        FoliosView()
            .background(Color.white)
            .frame(width: 200.0, height: 400.0)
    }
    //.windowToolbarStyle(.unified)
    .windowToolbarStyle(.unifiedCompact)
    //.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())


    Window("Elements", id: "elements") {
        ElementsView()
            .background(Color.white)
    }
    .windowToolbarStyle(UnifiedCompactWindowToolbarStyle())
    //.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())


#endif
```

I did read somewhere that this small titlebar isn't a standard anymore for this kind of windows; but it is used in a few Apple applications like Xcode. Is there a way to accomplish this? A later purpose is to snap more of them under each other like in Photoshop or SketchUp.